# How to edit an already saved post from the Firebase database using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to edit an already saved note from my notes-app and I think my code isn't correct. I used Firebase as my database and I'm also doing this with ReactJS.

I recently started using ReactJS and I'm trying to improve my coding skills. I have tried some code from other tutorials but still haven't got the desired result.

```js
this.db.ref("notes").on("child_changed", snapshot => {
  let note = {
    id: snapshot.key,
    title: snapshot.val().title,
    description: snapshot.val().description
  };
  const notes = [...this.state.notes];
  const index = notes.indexOf(note);
  notes[index] = { ...note };
  notes[index].title = "";
  notes[index].description = "";
  this.setState({ notes });
});
```

I expect that the notes can be edited and saved back in the database.

Comment: Nothing in the code you shared writes to the database. If you're just trying to write an update to the database for node in `child_changed`, you can do so with `snapshot.ref.update({ title: 'this is the new title] })`.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. But how do I go about this

Comment: Did you try the statement I gave you? What did it do? What doesn't work about it?